# Outlook 2003 attachment problem

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

Issue with attachments taking a long time to attach in outlook

When a user tries to attach a document in outlook they are able to browse to the documents on their local desktop (it really is local no redirects) right away, but when they click on the document to attach outlook will take about 1 minute to attach a PDF, the size of this PDF ranges from under a meg to 2 megs.

This started with one user and here are the steps I have taken

1. Deleted temp files
2. Checked installed programs to make sure nothing suspicious was installed.
3. Made sure all mapped drives were live and used.
4. Deleted outlook profile and recreated new one
5. Uninstalled office completely and reinstalled office
6. Uninstalled Kaspersky anti virus, which was doing email filtering.
7. Uninstall and reinstall office 2003.
8. Reinstall Kaspersky, making sure the email scanning feature was off

I can’t for the life of me figure out why attachments suddenly are taking so long to attach.  Any solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pro tip: `2003` just isn't a good tag.

Comment: sorry meant to make it outlook 2003

Comment: Is it only with PDFs? How much RAM does the PC have?

Comment: It happens with all attachments of any size.  These are new dual core PC's with 3 gigs of ram.

Comment: Can you try with another session on the user's computer and tell me if the problem still occurs? If not, create a new Windows profile for that user. Please, let me know!